# Title text for showing a failed exam

Tags: antonyms, titles, software

I have an exam system which tells the examinee whether they have passed or failed. This is displayed in the form of a title, and descriptive text below. A failure is not necessarily a big deal, as they may very well have the opportunity to retry at another point though this is not guaranteed.

A passed exam displays **Congratulations** in prominent letters and the related text.

For failed exams I chose **Commiserations** after wracking my brains. However, I'm unhappy with this as I feel it implies sadness or loss. Though I could perhaps be convinced otherwise.

Other options I considered were **Sorry** which felt too personal, **Exam Failed** which felt too blunt, and **Try Again** which may not apply depending on circumstance.

What other options have I missed that might be considered an appropriate antonym to **Congratulations**?

Comment: "Loser"! (I'm kidding, of course). Don

Comment: You could use _sorry_, it's not as personal as you think. If you were to ask a sales assistant for an item the business does not stock they might well say "I'm sorry we don't have that". Similarly a hotel receptionist might say "I'm sorry we do not have a room for tonight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just say it straight. Any dressing up probably won't be appreciated.

"You have not passed this time".